# I would like to pipe a list of files from a text file to prune from a find command

Tags: unix, command-line, text

I have a script which I pass a list of files to exclude from a spider function.

The problem is I have a list of files I want to include in the spider.  Rather than rewrite the function to also allow passing in a list of files I want to include I would like to pull a list of all files in the directory and then remove the list of files I want to include from it.

So my thought was to do a find of the directory and pipe in the list of files I want to include to prune out of the list so I have a list of files to exclude.

This sounds confusing, and there is probably a better way to do it, but this is my first idea.

Comment: You're right, it does sound confusing.  Paste what you currently have, and then paste what your *desired* change would be, even if its pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you need is to sort the list of all files into `file.1`, sort the list of files to be excluded into `file.2`, and then use `comm -23 file.1 file.2` to generate the files that can be allowed out.

Comment: This was a good option.  I decided that I need even more power than this though so it looks like I'm going to write a script.